# How to interpret CPLEX CP Optimizer Statistics page?

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

How can I interpret the solutions in CPLEX CP Optimizer Statistics page? I am trying to learn the definitions of each element.

[image]

Comment: Consider reading the official docs. Without any context, e.g.: your familiarity with the basic theory of *Constraint-Programming*, it's hard to find the right level of detail while answering. People familiar with CP usually will have a good idea in regards to all of these (without ever having used this solver) except maybe for: *choice points* (a cp optimizer related concept explained in the docs), *best bound* (when minimizing: proven lower-bound of the objective), *gap*: `|bestbound-objective|/(1e-10+|objective|)` (rather useless here; google `MIPGap` where the concept is coming from).

Answer (score 0):

The [CP search log](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=log-reading-search) is described in Cplex documentation.

CP Optimizer > CP Optimizer User's Manual > Search in CP Optimizer > The search log.

Reading a search log.

See also CP Optimizer > CP Optimizer User's Manual > Search in CP Optimizer.

Finally, also see this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=models-examining-statistics-progress-chart-cp).

[image: screenshot of documentation]

Comment: This answer is a little too "note form" to be fully understandable. What meaning is given by the sentence "Reading a search log"? Is that to be read in conjunction with the prior sentence i.e. a location in the documentation where something may be found?